# Expectations for checkboxes in (multi-select) list views

Tags: checkboxes, selection, multi-selection, windows-os, listview

I'm currently rewriting some parts of a Windows application and we have a list view (report style) where a user can use checkboxes to select/deselect items.

**The issue I'm having is** when a user selects multiple items and then clicks a checkbox, which items should be toggled? For example, given the following selection,

[image: List view with items selected]

If I click the checkbox for the first item, which items does the user expect to be toggled? I can't seem to find any guidelines for this.

Also, if the selection only covers one item, and the user toggles a non-selected item, should both change?

Comment: Personally, I would say that the if you click on 1st item you only toggle the 1st item, no matter what you have selected. As a user what I see are 2 different actions, selecting and clicking. Except, if these actions are connected. What will happen when I select the text "0_readme.txt"? Will I also deselect the box?

Comment: What is the purpose of "selecting"? The interaction is a mouse drag or it gets selected when clicking the text? My suggestion is to make the label check/uncheck the checkbox on click. Take a look to [this W3 example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_checkbox&stacked=h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest avoiding the double meaning of "selected". Thinking about: *selected* vs. *checked*, or: what is just *highlighted* vs. *selected* is not what Users should think about.

Therefore, I suggest removing the possibility to highlight multiple items in the first place, which will solve your problem as well.

Comment: Or removing the checkboxes, would also save some space.

Comment: Yes, however affecting affordance.